# Set up USB tethering ON Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, ethernet, linux-mint

I have an old laptop with an Ethernet port, whereas my new laptop does not have have one. I need an ethernet connection to be able to set up a headless server, but the old laptop is not fast enough to do this. I'm new-ish to networking, but how can I use the ethernet port and share that connection over a USB cable. Similar to USB Tethering on Android, but both machines would be laptops (Windows 7 connecting to Linux Mint).

Connection >*ethernet*> Windows 7 laptop >*USB*> Linux Mint laptop

Comment: You can make a headless server communicate over a WiFi connection, it’s inefficient, but possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Laptops only have USB host ports, so you can't even connect the two laptops through a USB cable.

There are special adapters to link two laptops through USB, but those don't make any sense in your scenario - it would be much easier (and cheaper) to buy a USB to Ethernet adapter, and leave out the old laptop altogether.

Comment: *leave out the old laptop altogether* is the best advice here, indeed. Please don't ever use obsolete, unsupported OSes online.